# Date value staying the same when changed by user (HTML)

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, date, datepicker

I wanted to use the HTML 5 datepicker for a website I was working on. The datepicker works and sets a value to it (using php), the code looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Date" value= <?php echo "'" . $row["datum"] . "'"; ?>>
```

Where $date is the date in YYYY-MM-DD. The date shows up, but if the user changes the date and hits submit the default value is sent to the server. Using inspect element I also see the "hardcoded" value stays there even when the datepicker is used to select a diffrent date.

Am I doing something wrong; is there a workaround.
It seems to be a problem with all input feelds I have noticed that some other form input fields with a default value also stopped working (I did not change the code of those!)

(P.s. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome (but it does the same on IE) for Windows 10 Technical Preview)

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: I already posted code but I accidentally didn't use the code tags, so you couldn't see it sorry about that!

Comment: Added additional information about the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

`<input type="date" name="bday" value='2014-10-30'>`

and you use instead:

`<input type="text"`

**date**, not **text**

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was handling vars wrong in the PHP code! But the only answer given was useful though it wouldn't have fixed my php code ;)